# SQL ERROR on INNER JOIN statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following error below for my sql query. I have been racking my head and can't seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

```
Error:
08-07-2013, 19:05:55: Database access error. Please contact the site administrator. SELECT * FROM realty_auctions WHERE id = 42962 INNER JOIN realty_agents ON realty_auctions.agentsid=realty_agents.agentsid; You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN realty_agents ON realty_auctions.agentsid=realty_agents.age' at line 3 page:/home/propoint/public_html/item.php line:567
```

SQL Query:

```
// get agent data
$query = "SELECT * FROM " realty_auctions WHERE id = " . $id ." INNER JOIN realty_agents ON " realty_auctions.agentsid=realty_agents.agentsid; ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$system->check_mysql($result, $query, __LINE__, __FILE__);
$agent_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $agent_data;
```

Comment: Did you make a copying mistake? Your quoting makes that invalid PHP syntax,

Comment: No, that is exactly how I have the code. I'm pretty new at this this is my first full function I'm trying to create.

Comment: You're not getting a parse error from PHP? `realty_auctions WHERE id =` should be inside the double quoted string.

Comment: No, I'm getting no error. I am trying to match up my property listing which has a column of agentsid and match it with a another table of agents that has the same column agentsid thus should spit out name, email, company, and phone number as that is what I have within the table for each agent. The WHERE id = " . $id ." is getting the propertyid.

Comment: I know what you're trying to do. The problem is that what you wrote isn't even a valid PHP statement. It shouldn't be running the way you've written it, you have improper use of doublequotes.

Comment: That is why I am coming here as I know I have something wrong and I need help in fixing it. I know it sucks to work with a n00b but I have been working on this for the last 6 hours before I tried to ask anyone for help. If you could please tell me how my code should be that would be great, otherwise thank you very much for your time. (not being sarcastic)

Comment: The problem is that the code you posted could not have caused the error you posted. The error comes from calling mysql_query(), and MySQL detecting an error in the SQL query, but if a PHP file doesn't parse it won't call anything at all. Is there really a doublequote between `FROM` and `realty_auctions` in your code?

Comment: This is my actual code currently after suggestions

http://pastebin.com/pZmR0n5g

Now i'm getting NULL back

Comment: I was asking about the original code, not the code after suggestions. Now you're missing `$agent_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`.

Comment: Please post updates by editing your question and adding changes at the end, not with pastebin.com.

Answer (score 3):

`join` must come before  `where`

```
SELECT * 
FROM realty_auctions au
INNER JOIN realty_agents ag ON au.agentsid = ag.agentsid
WHERE au.id = $id
```

And since probably both tables have an `id` column I suggest naming the table explicitly with `au.id`.

Comment: Your method is coming back with a response of Array and not the data from the matching agentsid table of realty_agents. I am trying to match up my property listing which has a column of agentsid and match it with a another table of agents that has the same id thus should spit out name, email, company, and phone number.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc()` returns an associative array, where the keys are the column names from the query and the values are the column values. You can't `echo` an array. Use `var_dump($agent_data)` to see the contents.